# Using FirebaseAuth in Flutter Web App in MS Teams

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, webview2

I'm trying to show my flutter web app that is using FirebaseAuth (with AzureAD/Entra SSO) in a MS Teams (the newer one) tab.

I'm using the following code in my flutter app to do the authentication:

```
final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
    microsoftProvider.setCustomParameters({'tenant': tenantId});
    if (kIsWeb) {
      await _auth.signInWithRedirect(microsoftProvider);
    } else {
      await _auth.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
    }
```

(the reason I'm using redirect and not popup is that MS Teams is not allowing popups)

Unfortunately the login fails with the following error in the teams developer console:

```
Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Using a regular browser just works fine, so it shouldn't be a problem with the configuration of the SSO itself.

I was able to find out that MS Teams (new) is using Edge Webview2 which is not allowing Third Party Cookies (via iFrame) which results in the above error.

Has anyone already successfully implemented a Firebase authentication with Azure/Entra that is working inside Teams or found a workaround to fix this?

Comment: 1.Ensure that the website used is iFramable and is included in the valid domains of the Manifest. This allows Teams to display your app within an iframe.
2.Set the Content-Security-Policy header to `'frame-ancestors teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com'`. This header allows your app to be displayed within an iframe on Teams.
3.For Internet Explorer 11 compatibility, set X-Content-Security-Policy. This header is used for compatibility with older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set the X-Frame-Options header to 'ALLOW-FROM https://teams.microsoft.com/'. This header allows your app to be displayed within an iframe specifically on the Teams website.

Comment: Tanks for the info @Prasad-MSFT. Could you point out where to set the header for 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'? Setting it in my main application has no effect and for my information changing the headers of EntraId is not possible.

As it is working in the Edge Browser (even the teams web app is working there): Is there something that can be configured within the teams app to behave the same like the Edge Browser?

Comment: 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options  2.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-http-headers-x-frame-options-on-iframe/

Comment: Sorry Prasad, I think I still don't get it. Your second link states this:
"One can set the X-Frame Options in the web-config of the site which is to be loaded in an iframe". 
I am loading "login.microsoftonline.com" in an i-frame within my app. It is not possible for me to set headers of "login.microsoftonline.com". This is all handled by Microsoft entra (as you can see in the domain) and it is not in my hands to change the headers here. All works fine in the teams browser version so I hoped that configuring the teams webview might help, but I found no option to configure it.

Comment: To set the X-Frame-Options header to 'ALLOW-FROM teams.microsoft.com' and allow your app to be displayed within an iframe specifically on the Teams website, you need to include the header in the HTTP response of your app. **Node.js:**
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://teams.microsoft.com/');
  next();
});   **C#:** protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM https://teams.microsoft.com/");
}

Comment: Additionally, it's important to note that the X-Frame-Options header is deprecated and not supported by all browsers. To ensure compatibility, you should also set the Content-Security-Policy header with the frame-ancestors directive.
Here's an example of how to set the Content-Security-Policy header in the HTTP response:
`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com`

This header allows your app to be displayed within iframes on the Teams website and other related domains.